# Assets javascript duplicate function name

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

Well I am new to rails and I am still experimenting a few things, so far I've read about RoR's assets pipeline not allowing duplicate file name ie `app/stylesheet/style.css.scss` and `vendor/stylesheet/style.css.scss` only the first one will have effect, ok, no problem I can handle that, but what about a function name in java script, let's say for example I want to call jquery's fade function but the one being called is the bootstrap-jquery's fade effect, I am assuming they both have the same name but different behavior...

in file[1].js.coffee I have

```
fadeEffect = function() {
   code segment[1]
};
```

and in the other I have file[2].js.coffee

```
fadeEffect = function() {
   code segment[2]
};
```

so they have different file name, but they have the same name for a given function, how do I go calling the 1st js file or the one in the 2nd file? They are both from a vendor and changing the name wouldn't be something elegant to do, so I wonder if there is a solution for this?

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two functions in the same scope with the same name and have access to both.  The last one defined (as determined by the order the javascript is parsed by the browser) is the one that will be in effect.

You will need to either contain the scope of these definitions so that they can't conflict with one another (e.g. they are not global and not in the same scope) or you will have to change the name of one of them.

If either one of them is only needed locally, you can perhaps enclose the code in an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) which creates a separate local scope so you can use something locally, but it isn't defined globally where it can conflict with other things.

```
// create new local function scope to isolate our variables so they dont
// overwrite other variables of the same name
(function() {

    // add var in front of the variable name to make it a local variable
    var fadeEffect = function() {
       code segment[2]
    }

    // use this copy of fadeEffect inside this function block
    // this other definition of fadeEffect will not be available here, but
    // this one won't override the other one outside this function scope


})();
```

Comment: I was affraid of this kind of answers, although it makes perfect sense, I was hopping that the rails team would come up with a solution.

Comment: @Coronellx - this is a text book example for why vendors should not define global javascript symbols with such generic and common names and, in fact, should use as few global variables as possible (often only one global that defines a namespace object).

Comment: Just a fun note - ES6 let fixes this - variables defined with `let` instead of `var` are local to the file they were created.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - interesting.  So there's a "file" scope you can opt into.  I wonder how many years until we can design assuming ES6 is available?

Comment: I was reading this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and I was wondering if it is possible to write your own compressor according to section 5.3 of that link, so that way you could modify what happens when you find a duplicated function, for example you could rename the second like s-fadeEffect for the second occurrence or prefix it with the directory and file name, for example, is this possible? or am I wrong?